# Change selected option in select (form)

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have an intial group of options like these:

```
<select name="item[type]">
    <option value="0" class="dr">First</option>
    <option value="1" class="dr">Second</option>
    <option value="2" class="dr">Third</option>
    <option value="3" class="dr">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

I want to check if a variable `isset($test)` is defined. If it is, then I want to change the option selected where the `value` is equal of `$test`. Something like this `<OPTION SELECTED>`

For example. `$test = 3`; so, the option selected should be fourth. If `$test` is empty or not defined, then the first should be the option that is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select name="item[type]" id="selectBoxId">
<option value="0" class="dr">First</option>
<option value="1" class="dr">Second</option>
<option value="2" class="dr">Third</option>
<option value="3" class="dr">Fourth</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = "<?= $test; ?>";
    if (test != '' && parseInt(test)) {
        document.getElementById('selectBoxId').selectedIndex = test;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I would only use JavaScript to alter the DOM after some kind of user input. In this case however you already know which option should be selected, so there is no need to use JavaScript. Instead, make sure the DOM already has all the right information using purely PHP logic to add the selected attribute in the right place. Also, the only way this works is to add the JavaScript to the same page so that you can access the PHP variable, or to add the variable somewhere hidden in the DOM so you'll be able to retrieve it with an external JS script. Both far from ideal.

Comment: Oh I absolutely agree. But we don't know how his scripts are organized or if they're even split up. Perhaps he's using some template system for which variables can be defined or whatever the case.. I was merely providing a simple solution to the very limited information that was given to me.  Nevertheless, I appreciate your disposition and agree with it wholeheartedly.

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
<select name="item[type]">
    <option <?=$test==0?'selected="selected"':'';?> value="0" class="dr">First</option>
    <option <?=$test==1?'selected="selected"':'';?> value="1" class="dr">Second</option>
    <option <?=$test==2?'selected="selected"':'';?> value="2" class="dr">Third</option>
    <option <?=$test==3?'selected="selected"':'';?> value="3" class="dr">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

Another:

```
<? $selected[$test] = 'selected="selected"'; ?>

<select name="item[type]">
    <option <?=$selected[0];?> value="0" class="dr">First</option>
    <option <?=$selected[1];?> value="1" class="dr">Second</option>
    <option <?=$selected[2];?> value="2" class="dr">Third</option>
    <option <?=$selected[3];?> value="3" class="dr">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is sooo clever! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Remove "[type]" from select name, make it simple to "item".
Then execute this code.

`$test = isset($_POST['item']) ? $_POST['item'] : "0";`

Answer (score 1):

```php
// assuming you are using a loop: in the loop where you create the options
  $selected_html = $test == $loop_var ? ' selected="selected" ' : '';
  echo "<option value=\"$loop_var\" class=\"dr\"$selected_html>$text</option>";
```