# how to put value in select option

Tags: php, html

I have select option in my page or drop down list,my problem is how can i set value
in my select option and this value is from the database,

here is my code.

```
  <select name="status" value="<?php echo $status; ?>" >

    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="public">public</option>
    <option value="private">private</option>
  </select>
```

on top of my html tag

```
   if(isset($_GET['status']))
    {
         $status = $_GET['status'];
     $sstatus="select .......";


   foreach($db->query($sstatus) as $rows)
    {
      $status= $rows['status'];
      ......
              ......
              ......
         }
   }
```

I tried modify my code and it's seems working but my problem is that it has 2  same 
value in the drop down list.

```
   <select name="status" >

    <option selected="selected"><?php echo $status; ?></option>
    <option value="public">public</option>
    <option value="private">private</option>
  </select>
```

it will show like this in my drop down list,my question for this is this is the right way
in displaying the values that comes from the database.

public 
public 
private

Comment: Is $status filled? Because that code should be working. Is PHP correctly installed and running? (try <?php phpinfo(); ?> to check this)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973908/change-selected-option-in-select-form

Comment: @LeonCullens, I already used isset on top my page and that $status has already value,but i get stuck in displaying in drop down list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="status" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="public"<?php if (isset($status) && $status === 'public') echo 'selected'; ?>>public</option>
    <option value="private"<?php if (isset($status) && $status === 'private') echo 'selected'; ?>>private</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: How can i use if statement if i am going to echo the option?i have also day and by displaying it i use for loop and then i echo the option but i could not use the if statement inside the option.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $options = array('', 'public', 'private') ?>

<select name="status">
<?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $option ?>" <?php echo isset($status) && $status == $option ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>><?php echo $option ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>

</select>
```